# How to get all my values within the same categorie to be equal in my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I have a dataset that looks just like that :

```
      site year territories cat
1      10 2017         0.0   1
2      10 2016          NA   NA
3      10 2015         2.0   1
4      10 2014          NA   NA
5      10 2013          NA   NA
6      11 2012          NA   NA
7      11 2011         0.0   2
8      11 2010          NA   NA
9      11 2009         1.0   2
```

But I do not want to have NAs in the `cat` column. Instead, I want every line within the same site to get the same value of `cat`.

Just like this :

```
      site year territories cat
1      10 2017         0.0   1
2      10 2016          NA   1
3      10 2015         2.0   1
4      10 2014          NA   1
5      10 2013          NA   1
6      11 2012          NA   2
7      11 2011         0.0   2
8      11 2010          NA   2
9      11 2009         1.0   2
```

Any idea on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `na.aggregate` to fill in the NA values using `ave` to do it by `site`.

```
library(zoo)
transform(DF, cat = ave(cat, site, FUN = na.aggregate))
```

giving:

```
  site year territories cat
1   10 2017           0   1
2   10 2016          NA   1
3   10 2015           2   1
4   10 2014          NA   1
5   10 2013          NA   1
6   11 2012          NA   2
7   11 2011           0   2
8   11 2010          NA   2
9   11 2009           1   2
```

### Note

The input used, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "
      site year territories cat
1      10 2017         0.0   1
2      10 2016          NA   NA
3      10 2015         2.0   1
4      10 2014          NA   NA
5      10 2013          NA   NA
6      11 2012          NA   NA
7      11 2011         0.0   2
8      11 2010          NA   NA
9      11 2009         1.0   2"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete base R alternative:

```
transform(DF, cat = ave(cat, site, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]))
```

which gives:

> ```
>   site year territories cat
> 1   10 2017           0   1
> 2   10 2016          NA   1
> 3   10 2015           2   1
> 4   10 2014          NA   1
> 5   10 2013          NA   1
> 6   11 2012          NA   2
> 7   11 2011           0   2
> 8   11 2010          NA   2
> 9   11 2009           1   2
> ```

The same logic implemented with  `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(cat = na.omit(cat)[1])
```

---

Or with `na.locf` of the `zoo`-package:

```
library(zoo)
transform(DF, cat = ave(cat, site, FUN = function(x) na.locf(na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE))))
```

---

Or with `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(site) %>%
  fill(cat) %>%
  fill(cat, .direction = "up")
```

---

NOTE: I'm wondered what the added value is of the `cat`-column when `cat` has to be the same for each `site`. You'll end up with two grouping variables that do exactly the same, thus making one ot them redundant imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `tidyr::fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  fill(cat,.direction = "up")   %>%
  fill(cat,.direction = "down") %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#    site  year territories   cat
#   <int> <int>       <dbl> <int>
# 1    10  2017           0     1
# 2    10  2016          NA     1
# 3    10  2015           2     1
# 4    10  2014          NA     1
# 5    10  2013          NA     1
# 6    11  2012          NA     2
# 7    11  2011           0     2
# 8    11  2010          NA     2
# 9    11  2009           1     2
```

Comment: I don’t think this is doing what OP wants because it’s not `grouped_by` the `site` var.